# Alternative to WiFi Direct

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, tethering

I'm trying to develop an application that, when run on two or more devices, will be able to send data to each other at high speed. Bluetooth is not an option because of the distance. I wanted to use Direct WiFi, but it's available only on Android 4.0 and onwards. Even though I have devices with Android 4.0.3, it's still not functioning. The discovery function is not present in this version I think. I've tried looking for alternatives, such as [WiFi Tethering](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/) but the device needs to be rooted in order for it to work. Moreover, there's no tutorial explaining how it works. Can anyone give me another alternative to WiFi Direct, which would enable me to create an AdHoc network on the fly?

Comment: maybe u should try AllJoyn library @J-P,

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, you can use the new NFC communication, but, if your phone doesn´t have WiFi Direct... It is not going to have NFC communication. Anyway, i hope this may help you.